# Nodejs: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'endianness'

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I try to run server: node app.js on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS then get this error:

```
/home/ubuntu/Ytutor_Server/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/shared.js:18
var nodejsversion = f('Node.js %s, %s', process.version, os.endianness());
                                                            ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'endianness'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/Ytutor_Server/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/shared.js:18:61)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/Ytutor_Server/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:11:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
```

I have no idea what's wrong with this. I use Nodejs v6.9 and Mongodb v3.2.11, it should have module os that content 'endianness'?

Comment: How did you instantiate `os` ?

Comment: I didn't. These files generated in node_modules (mongodb)

Comment: Are you using webpack or browserify or something similar that might be transforming your node modules? Otherwise if `node -v` shows at least `v0.10.xx`, then there should be no problem. `os.endianness()` did not exist in node v0.8 or earlier.

Comment: I see in Nodejs Docs there exists module os and endianness() (https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/os.html#os_os_endianness), i don't know why it didn't work. I run server on my Window laptop and it worked correctly

Comment: @mscdex: oh really? I see mine current is v0.8.22

Comment: and i just use npm install to get node modules

Comment: @mscdex: excuse me but why there exists node and node.js? i just think they're one. i see my node -v is v0.8.22 and nodejs -v is  v6.9.2. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that an older version of node is being used to run the script(s) (pre-v0.10 in this case). `os.endianness()` was added in node v0.10.0 (technically v0.9.x).

The reason for separate `node` and `nodejs` binaries on Linux is that some distributions (namely Debian-based) do that to avoid a conflict in package names. Before node.js, the 'node' package name was already being used by an amateur radio package, so when node.js became officially packaged by Debian they chose a different name ('nodejs') rather than replace the existing 'node' package. To also confuse things further, both packages use the same binary names, so that also had to be changed to avoid *any* potential confusion. This does present some problems though for shebangs that assume the `node` binary name.

Since most developers do not use the 'node' amateur radio package, one popular solution to the whole `node`/`nodejs` naming issue is to simply use a third-party repository (such as [NodeSource's](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions)) that not only provides the latest versions of node but they also use the 'node' binary name in their packages.